# Query is read-only probably due to an aggregated value

Tags: ms-access, aggregate, readonly, datasheet

There is an existing MS-Access project (not done by me), where people want to get an **additional column** into a data sheet for advanced filters.

Just imagine a simple straight-forward query filled to a **form in data sheet view**. People can use built-in filters and sort options.

For the underlying table (let's call it `MainTable`) there is another related table with audit data (call it `AuditTable`). Any change in `MainTable` is written to this `AuditTable` and must be accepted by a super-user in another process.

Now I want to **add the count of audit lines** which are not accepted yet to the visible data sheet. Something like

```
SELECT Count(*) AS OpenAudit 
FROM AuditTable 
WHERE MainTableID=MainTable.ID --<-- MainTableID is the FK in AuditTable onto the ID of MainTable
  AND Accepted=0
GROUP BY MainTableID
```

It works great to add this to the underlying query and display the value in a new column. Filtering, sorting, all works well. I tried it as well as a *sub-selected column* and as a *side query joined in the from clause*.

### But now there is this problem:

The data sheet is read-only suddenly. Users cannot change any data there anymore.

I found, that a query *containing aggregated data* and/or *sub-selects* or queries constisting of *stacked queries* will lead to read-only recordsets [(list by Allen Brown)](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html).

### And here's the question:

Is there any approach to include such data in a recordset without changing the RecordSource to a *read-only* set?

### Some simple sample data

```
MainTable
ID    SomeValue   OneMore
 1       val 1      more 1
 2       val 2      more 2
 3       val 3      more 3

AuditTable
ID    MainTableID   Accepted  --(+ more columns with fieldname, valueBefore and valueAfter etc)
 1         1            1
 2         1            0
 3         2            1
 4         3            0
 5         3            0

 The expected Result
 ID    SomeValue   OneMore    CountOfOpenAudits
 1       val 1      more 1            1
 2       val 2      more 2            0
 3       val 3      more 3            2
```

This additional column should be somehow visible in the user's GUI without changing the recordset to *read-only*.

Hope this is clear, TIA!

Comment: If DCount() destroys performance, about the only other option is to insert the result of your above query into a temp table, and join that to the main table for the record source. But you will need ways to keep the data current when needed.

Comment: Or, if the underlying data comes e.g. from SQL Server, create and link a view, and base the form on that.

Comment: If it's a form, then don't include the aggregate in the record source. Instead, add a textbox and set that textbox equal to the domain aggregate. This allows lazy loading and will improve performance.

Comment: @ErikA, thank you for your input. After testing around with `DCount` I can say, that it works and the performance is good enough. If things get bigger (and therefore slower), I'll come back to your suggestion.

Comment: @Andre, As written below the answer by Lee Mac DCount worked it out pretty well. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a domain aggregate function such as [DCount](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3), though, it will be slower.

For example:

```
select t.*, dcount("*","AuditTable","MainTableID=" & t.ID & " and Accepted=0") as OpenAudits
from MainTable t
```

Comment: I did a lot with MS-Access some years ago, but I had forgotten the D-functions. Thx, DCount did the trick and the performance is sufficient in this rather tiny case...